# RadGrid MVC Column Formationg

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

I am using the following line of code to format the data in my RadGrid column:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Price).Format("${0:0.00}");
```

It works fine when the item has a price but throws a NullReferenceException when the price field is null.

Comment: Is the RadGrid controls different from the ASP.net MVC extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your model defined to accept null for the Price field, there is nothing in the RadGrid that should throw a NullReferenceException. Just to make sure I build a dummy grid that has a bound column that matches the code in your question. In my model, I set the value of the price field to null for one of the items. The result was just an empty cell for that item.

[image]